# Find an equation involving g,h,k that makes the augmented matrix > correspond to a consistent system.

Tags: linear-algebra

$
\begin{array}{ccc}{1}&{\mathrm{{-}}{4}}&{{7}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}}&{g}\\{0}&{3}&{\mathrm{{-}}{5}}&{h}\\{\mathrm{{-}}{2}}&{5}&{\mathrm{{-}}{9}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}}&{k}\end{array}
$

Shown above is augmented matrices and the question is

> Find an equation involving g,h,k that makes the augmented matrix
>   correspond to a consistent system.

After R2/3 , R3+2R1 and R3+R2, I got

$1 \hspace{5pt}-4   \hspace{10pt}  7  \hspace{10pt}   g \\$

$0 \hspace{5pt}1 \hspace{5pt}  -5/3  \hspace{10pt}   h/3 \\$

$0\hspace{5pt}0 \hspace{5pt}  1 \hspace{5pt}   (h+k+2g)/7 \\$

Which tells me that h,k,g can have any value for the system to be consistent, but the answer given is h+k+2g=0

I feel it should be h+k+2g=a

Comment: Last line should read $0\hspace{5pt}0 \hspace{5pt}  0 \hspace{5pt}   (h+k+2g)/7 \\$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe,got my mistake,thanx for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, reduce the given matrix into echelon form. Then the last row will be in the form $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & k+2g+h\end{bmatrix}.$$ For a matrix to be consistent, all the elements in the last row of the matrix should be zero. Therefore, $k+2g+h=0$ is the answer.